# Populate date fields on multiple records using a formula?

Tags: formula, process-builder, datetime, field-update, loop

So we have a custom object called '**Sessions**' (child). Sessions are automatically created via a trigger for a '**Course**' (parent). Now depending on the value of the '**Level**' field (on the **Course**) object, a different number of 'Sessions' are created.

Each of these Sessions has dates which are currently filled manually. Every single session occurs weekly (on the same day i.e every Wednesday). I need help creating a formula to calculate these date and populate them (ALL ARE **DATETIME** FIELD VALUES).

All dates will be populated based on the **Session 1 Planned Date**, here is the structure it should follow:

If **Session Name** CONTAINS **'Session 2'** then populate **'Session Planned Date'** = **Session 1 + 7**

If **Session Name** CONTAINS **'Session 3'** then populate **'Session Planned Date'** = **Session 1 + 14**

If **Session Name** CONTAINS **'Session 4'** then populate **'Session Planned Date'** = **Session 1 + 21**

If **Session Name** CONTAINS **'Session 5'** then populate **'Session Planned Date'** = **Session 1 + 28**

If **Session Name** CONTAINS **'Session 6'** then populate **'Session Planned Date'** = **Session 1 + 35**

If **Session Name** CONTAINS **'Session 7'** then populate **'Session Planned Date'** = **Session 1 + 42**

If **Session Name** CONTAINS **'Session 8'** then populate **'Session Planned Date'** = **Session 1 + 49**

If **Session Name** CONTAINS **'Session 9'** then populate '**Session Planned Date'** = **Session 1 + 56**

If **Session Name** CONTAINS **'Session 10'** then populate **'Session Planned Date'** = **Session 1 + 63**

If **Session Name** CONTAINS '**Session 11'** then populate **'Session 
Planned Date'** = **Session 1 + 70**
**UNTIL SESSION 80.**

How would I go about doing this?

Any help is much appreciated :)
Many Thanks,
Natasha

Comment: It might be easier to edit your trigger to do this for you

Comment: Hi Kasper, thanks for that. I don't really want to be editing the trigger as that works on the COURSE and we need it to run when Session 1 is populated (dates will be based on Session 1)

Comment: If you store the session 1 date on the course record then you could do this with a formula. If the session 1 date is stored only on the first record then you could still do something like this but you would have to use the process builder, perhaps in combination with a flow. Unfortunately you can't use a formula to get data from a sibling record so if that's what you want to do then you're out of luck. If you are familiar with process builder and flows (or apex) then i'd recommend that because they will allow you (in the future) to for instance skip holidays and things like that automatically.